# Drupal get nodes by type xml-rpc

Tags: drupal, xml-rpc

I try to get nodes by type from D7 over xml-rpc.
I used this example:http://drupal.org/node/1304802
This example provide an xml to create a node...

Anyone can help me how to get nodes by type like this XML?

Thanks,

IB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work. I have just tested it on my Drupal installation using the Firefox plugin called [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/poster/).

Remember to set the **correct** URL to your endpoint. Considering a Drupal instance on `http://localhost/test` and an endpoint called "api", the resulting URL to access the endpoint is `http://localhost/test/?q=api`.

One last thing: if you have enabled authentication for your endpoint you must access the node with a user which has permissions to do so. You can set the username and password when using [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/poster/).

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>node.retrieve</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>nid</name>
            <value>
              <string>INSERT THE NODE'S ID HERE</string>
            </value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```